# What is &#13;?

Tags: html, entities

In html made by fckeditor i find the following character:

```
&#13;
```

What is this character?

Answer (score 41):

Looks like the ASCII code for Carriage Return, encoded as an XML character reference.

Comment: Numerical character references refer to character of Unicode’s character set and not ASCII’s. (Although the first 128 character of Unicode’s and ASCII’s character set is identical.)

Comment: I've filtered it out...But the thing is that i forgot if i pass it through to PHP it was rendered as a carriage return. So to make a good if statement i had to use htmlentities(trim('&#13')) to campare it.

Answer (score 18):

When you code in windows, and use "DOS/Windows" line endings, the your lines will end like this "\r\n".
In some xhtml editors, that "\r" is illegal so te editor converts it to "&#13".