# API yields weird characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

Im connecting to an external API which returns messages with the character

Response:

```
<daoapi>
  <status>FEJL</status>
  <fejlkode>520</fejlkode>
  <fejltekst>Fejl ved opslag: Der er fejl i input parametre:&#13;
Husnummer mangler eller er ikke numerisk&#13;
</fejltekst>
</daoapi>
```

It's in danish, but you can see the characters occuring twice

How can I escape this?

Comment: Can you show us more code, like the API call?

Comment: updated code with full response

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is &#13;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459170/what-is-13)

Comment: When you say "escape this", what precisely do you mean?  Do you mean that you want to turn that character into its unicode equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the XML response with [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org), it handles entity conversion.

```
require 'nokogiri'

response = <<-XML
<daoapi>
  <status>FEJL</status>
  <fejlkode>520</fejlkode>
  <fejltekst>Fejl ved opslag: Der er fejl i input parametre:&#13;
Husnummer mangler eller er ikke numerisk&#13;
</fejltekst>
</daoapi>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(response)
doc.at_xpath('//fejltekst').text
#=> "Fejl ved opslag: Der er fejl i input parametre:\r\nHusnummer mangler eller er ikke numerisk\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's no *weird character* but an ASCII-encoded character interpretable as an Carriage Return. Check [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/) or any other reference.

You can either reencode you output to change it to `\n`, a [html entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) or probably leave it like that as it will cause no harm.