# PHP trim non standard characters from the string

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to save an XML file with a string pulled out of a text file (which is actually a converted PDF to TXT file). In CMD (php.exe) the echo command shows the string normally, without any extra characters, but in an XML file I get a different input.

This is the string that I am trying to save.

```
Ponedjeljak
```

In CMD it shows it like this

```
Ponedjeljak\n
```

While in XML the string is stored with some extra characters, like this

```
Ponedjeljak
&#13;
```

I have tried using preg_replace like this

```
preg_replace("/&#\\d+;|\n/", "", $dan);
```

But the string and the extra line are still saved in the XML. What am I doing wrong here and why is it saving the extra characters in the XML file? Both PHP and XML files are in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
```

Comment: So the &#13 represents a newline character?

Comment: Looks like a carriage return
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459170/what-is-13